# C++ class as namespace for static values

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

Is there anyway to have the same API from namespace with a class

Exemple for namespace :

```cpp
namespace Direction
{
    static const vec3 up = vec3(0, 1, 0);
}

// in code
{
   vec3 v = Direction::up;
}
```

whereas using a class I have to use a method

```cpp
class Color : public vec4
{
    // class stuff //

    static Color black() {return Color(0, 0, 0, 1);}
}

// in code
{
   Color c = Color::black();
}
```

I want to be able to use `Color c = Color::black;` with Color being a class and black being defined in header. Is there any way to do it ?

EDIT : an other way to put it around is :
Why does this gives me "incomplete type not allowed" and "a member of 'const Color' cannot have and in-class initializer"

```cpp
class Color : public glm::vec4
{
public:
    explicit Color(const float r, const float g, const float b, const float a = 1.0f)
        : glm::vec4(r, g, b, a) {}

    static const Color a = Color(1, 1, 1, 0); // error
}
```

Comment: `class A { public: static A b = ... }`

Comment: for such use, prefer the approach with a `enum class`

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT "a member of type "const Color" cannot have an in-class initializer"

Comment: @grybouilli - How do you pack a class with multiple (potentially non-integer) fields into an enum class?

Comment: @grybouilli can't be enum class as it has other fields and methods

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica true, altho for the given example, it is common to wrap color values in an enum class and make a function that translates the enum value to the desired value type ie possibly non-integer.

Comment: @startresse you need the field to be const to solve the error you're getting

Comment: @grybouilli check the edit please, and as mentioned in my comment response const doesn't work, static or not either btw

Comment: @startresse you're trying to define a member variable of type Color inside a class Color: this not authorized. You can only have pointers to the class you're defining

Comment: @grybouilli yeah, I figured, so is there a way to have the same API as a namespace (ie `Color::black` instead of `Color::black()`) with a Class or not ?

Comment: what if you define black as type glm::vec4? it would work but wouldn't have type Color, idk if it's what you want

Comment: how about you do an enum class inside your class Color and make a conversion operator from the enum to the class

Comment: @grybouilli that's not what I want, my class `Color` extends `glm::vec4` with extra functionalities, that's why I'm not using a namespace as I did with `Direction`. And I want to use `Color::black` in my code for easier reading

Comment: the enum class can't have the same name, so I could also use a namespace Color and I would work but I would like to use the name of the class so there wouldn't be any ambiguity around the type of the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
class Color 
{
    public:
    Color(int x, int y, int z, int t)
    {}
    const static Color BLACK;
};
const Color Color::BLACK{1,2,3,4};

int main()
{
   Color c = Color::BLACK;
}
```

I tested at https://godbolt.org/z/4oP55jTMK

Comment: The line `const Color Color::BLACK{1,2,3,4};` has to be put in a separate cpp file because the `static` keyword is not there for multiple inclusion to not redefine the variable (`one or more multiply defined symbols found`) but it works thanks!